# Trying to populate the datatable with php ajax mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to populate my datatable from mysql database. Everything works fine but when I try to see my table it says:

> DataTables warning: table id=manageProductTable - Invalid JSON response.
>
> For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

I've already checked console and I can see my list there as:

```
connection success {
    "data": [
        ["tulum","rtert","6","12.30","dfsdfsdf"],
        ["body","bd56","8","56,30","dfsdfsdf"],
        ["dfdsf","dsfdsf","8","56,32","dsfdsfsd"],
        ["","saf","8","25.90","dsfdsfsd"],
        ["tulum","FWNWP","","","dsfdsfsd"],
        ["bluz","dd56","6","78","dsfdsfsd"],
        ["dsfdsf","sdfsdf","9","23","chicco"],
        ["atlet","ATL30","30","23,30","chicco"],
        ["BODY","56FG","6","56,30","dsfdsfsd"]
    ]
}
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

JS

```
$('#manageProductTable').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        'url': 'php_action/fetchProduct.php',
        'dataSrc': 'features'},
        'columns': [
            {"data":"Name"},
            {"data":"Code"},
            {"data":"Brand"},
            {"data":"Quantity"},
            {"data":"Price"},
        ]
});
```

PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT product.product_id, product.product_name, 
               product.product_code, product.brand_id,
               product.quantity, product.price, brand.brand_name 
        FROM product 
        INNER JOIN brand ON product.brand_id = brand.brand_id";

$result = $connect->query($sql);    
$output = array('data' => array());
if($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    $active = ""; 
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $brandName = $row[6];
        $output['data'][]= array(       
            $row[1],         
            $row[2],         
            $row[4],         
            $row[5],       
            $brandName,
        );  
    }
}
$connect->close();
echo json_encode($output);
```

I have one more php file but it's just to build web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is doing "connection success" there?
That is altering your response.

Comment: that was my database connection control. Thanks!